# Merge [email-rules] and [email-filter]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-request

[email-rules](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-rules) has 1 follower and <strike>61</strike> 67 uses:

> Actions performed automatically on incoming or outgoing messages, based on conditions that you specify.

[email-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-filter) has 0 followers and <strike>48</strike> 51 uses:

> Email filters allow custom actions to be performed when a message satisfies the filter/rule requirements is received. An example of a common email filter is spam protection, which automatically moves all incoming messages into a Spam folder (action), when a given message is determined to be "spam" (rule).

Based on their definitions, these tags are clearly synonyms. I'd like to merge them. [email-rules](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-rules) has the slight edge in usage, so I suppose [email-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-filter) should be made a synonym of that.

Comment: I partly agree, because I don't think most people make much distinction.  For me, a rule is something users do on their E-mail client and filters are something I apply at the MTA level, but its mostly a distinction without a difference.